# How do i view a file on the managed host?

Tags: ansible

I have used the simple user playbook to create a user on the managed host. Now even though I know it has worked, I want to check the /etc/passwd file of the managed host on the control node. 
How do i view a file on the managed host through Ansible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- name: View File
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:

  - name: Cat /etc/password
    shell: cat /etc/passwd
    register: file_out

  - debug:
      var: file_out.stdout_lines
```